# ./configure gives error in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

While installing `eclipse.tar.gz` and when I used `./configure` command,it returned me the following error:

```
"bash: ./configure: No such file or directory"
```

How to solve this error, so that I can install eclipse on my system.

Comment: Did you unpack the tarball, step into the unpacked directory, and *then* run `./configure`? OT: Do you have any particular reason to not install Eclipse from the repositories?

Comment: yes @Biffen,i want to learn linux,so i go for installing it from terminal,yes i had unpacked my .tar.gz file,it had extracted it into a folder called eclipse,now i moved to that folder and then run ./configure so that gave me the above error.

Comment: Installing from repositories can be done from a terminal too. What you're attempting looks more like compiling it from source, which is fine, but if you get stuck at this step then maybe it's not for you just yet. `./configure` simply means "execute the file called `configure` in *this* directory, and Bash is telling you there's no such file. Where did you get the instructions to use that command? I suggest looking *there* for help, and if you still can't work it out then *consider* using a ready-made package.

Answer (score 3):

First make sure you are in that directory. Then before you use ./configure command.

```
$ autoreconf -i
```

and then ./configure. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I installed 'pmars-0.9.2' (its was unpacked from pmars-0.9.2.tar.gz) on Ubuntu 18.04, but with `./configure` i also got a similar **bash: ./configure: No such file or directory** error. For the correct use of the command `autoreconf -i` i wrote in sequence:

```
# automake
# apt install automake
# apt install automake1.11
# autoreconf -i
```

and for me this already goes into another error:

> `autoreconf: 'configure.ac' or 'configure.in' is required`